# Actionscript read XML and write on List

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, list, save

I'm trying to save the contents of a XML file on a list, but I'm getting this error: `1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon.`

Note:  I think Im missing an `import` stuff, but I tried `flash.net.List` and didnt do a thing.

```
 package 
 {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest; 

public class Main extends MovieClip
{

    public function Main()
    {
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);

        function loadXML(e:Event):void
        {
            var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

                var nodes = xml.firstChild.childNodes;
                for(var i:int =0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
                    lista.addItem(label: nodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue, data: i);
                }
        }

        loader.load(new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1:8090/NewProj/index.php?tipo=get"));
    }
}
 }
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is on this line:

```
lista.addItem(label: nodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue, data: i);
```

You need to wrap this syntax (`key: value, key: value`) in curly braces, which initializes an `Object` with properties represented by `key` and their corresponding values represented by `value`.

```
lista.addItem({label: nodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue, data: i});
```

`addItem()` should also expect an `Object` as its first and only required argument.

Comment: There's nothing else in the code you've posted that would cause this error. Maybe run through your code with `CTRL+F` to find all instances of `: ` and see if you've wrapped everything else like this in `{}`.